# android onresume - conflict with AlertDialog

Tags: android, onresume

In my app I am using location services, and after first install the app asks for Location permission. If the user click OK, permission is granted, if Cancel, then I have another dialog with some info.

Then - if the user has turned off the GPSon his device, a dialog will come up which asks to enable GPS - if Ok is clicked, the device settings are opened and here the user can enable the GPS.

As far as now everything works fine. But I need to restart the activity after the user is back from settings. (So I can load some items according the location).

For this I used onresume():

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() { //restart activity after back from GPS settings

    String action = getIntent().getAction();
    // Prevent endless loop by adding a unique action, don't restart if action is present
    if(action == null || !action.equals("created")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Okoli.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    // Remove the unique action so the next time onResume is called it will restart
    else
        getIntent().setAction(null);

    super.onResume();
}
```

I used there a unique action to avoid loop restart, so in oncreate I am setting also `getIntent().setAction("created");`

Now this is working fine - the activity restarts after the user is back from settings, but it conflicts with Permission dialog which I mentioned as first.

So if I have the onResume function, and the user installs the app, the Location permission dialog comes up, but in this case the user can't click CANCEL, because the dialog is looping forever if he clicks cancel. So it is appearing again and again until he clicks OK.

When I remove the whole onResume section from my code, then the Permission dialog works fine, but I need onresume for restarting activity.

Answer (score 0):

okey, finally I store a value to SharedPreferences - when user doesn't allow the location access, and then I check this value onResume and only restart the activity if the value is not set. Works fine!